# Can you explain how the following garden solar light circuit works?

Tags: led, transistors, resistors, solar-cell, light

I found the following circuit in a solar garden light. The cut off white and black wires are from the solar panel. What does the 4 pin transistor do? [image]

[image]

[image: The solar cell used to charge the 200mah aaa battery]

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The "4 pin transistor" is an integrated circuit such as the QX5251, which combines battery charging, light sensing, and voltage boost circuitry in a single package.

[image: QX5251 internals]

Comment: And under voltage cut off

Comment: Please not that it's not a 4 pin transistor - it's an IC in a package that looks similar to that of a typical transistor.